# Subject and extra information

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning

I'm learning Japanese on Duolingo.

I was wondering:

学校は日本にあります means 'The school is in Japan'

What is the difference between 学校は日本にあります and the Japanese translation of 'There is a school in Japan'? I thought arimasu could be translated as 'there is'...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question title asks about です, but you don't mention です anywhere in the question itself.  Could you please [edit] your question to clarify a bit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am not mistaken this question is not about です at all (if so, please change the title). It seems to be a matter of focus and of what is already known.

> 学校**は**日本にあります。

means 'Talking about the school, it is in Japan.' We know of the school and we give extra information about it.

On the other hand,

> 日本に(は)学校**が**あります。

takes Japan for granted (so to speak) and we say something about it: 'In Japan there are schools.'